# How can I search for a File and read the content line by line?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I want to search for a file `test.txt` in `someDir`. If the file is found I want to read the content line by line. I know how to do this in Java.

How can do this in Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle is basically [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code, and to parse a file line by line it is:

```
File f = new File(someDir, "test.txt")
if (f.exists()) {
  f.eachLine { line ->
    // do something with line
  }
}
```

If by 'search' you mean recursively look for this file in subfolders, then it looks more like:

```
new File(someDir).eachFileRecurse { file ->
  if (file.name == 'test.txt) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the files does not exist? How do I create and save it?

Comment: Many ways to do that, one is to use `f.setTest('foobar')`, others involve using `withWriter`, you can find all the groovy File methods there: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html